"No include path in which to find stdio.h" error
I get this error when I try to run a C program:

E:\c_stuff>gcc frist_c.c -o frist_c
frist_c.c:1: No include path in which to find stdio.h

But I already did reinstall MinGW and added the C:\minGW\bin to the path, yet, I still get this error.
How can I solve it?
This is the mingw vertion I'm using "gcc (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0"

What does where gcc print?

Your installation is too old anyway. 6.3.0 is from 2016 or so. Wipe it, make sure there is no gcc on your system, and install msys2.

What makes you expect a header in bin? In my installation that folder only has exe and dlls, which to me matches the folder name. Where do you have that header in your installation? At all? It should never be necessary to bother, because the one thing a compiler installation will always know to find it probably that header. I only ask because I suspect that you omitted details on what is special about your environment.

Please repeat your command with an additional -v option added (at the end is fine). This will make it spew a bunch of diagnostic output. Copy and paste the complete and unedited output into your question. You may have to scroll back to get all of it.
